# Wireless Access Point Won't Delete and Automatically Connects

Tags: networking, wireless, hot-spot

I tried setting up my laptop as a wireless access point. Now when I start up my machine, or take it back out of hibernation it connects itself to the wireless hotspot that I set up. I'm not sure why it would want to do this in the first place - connecting to its own wi-fi hotspot.

It is incredibly annoying, having to disconnect, disable the wi-fi and then connect to the actual wi-fi network I want to connect to.

I have tried deleting this connection in the network connections, but it still continues to happen. I had a look in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` for the connection but it isn't there.

Any bright ideas would be most appreciated!

I'm using 14.04, on a sony vaio pro 13.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you changed the wifi card mode from Master back to Managed?

Comment: Hey Serg, thanks for the response. The wifi card is already in managed mode, i'm afraid...

Comment: did you manage to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` check your "Wireless connection XX" items - you may have created a connection to an access point manually and are not seeing that it's actually connecting to one of those - happened to me.